# Wordpress custom post type network error

Tags: wordpress

I've created a custom post type for my wordpress theme named "Questions". But if i go to url:
`www.mysite.com/questions` it wont work and returning:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found

However, the url of specific product: `www.mysite.com/questions/my-question` works fine.

What is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

will be a .htaccess problem or something wrong with mod_rewrite.
maybe this can help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

If your htaccess is ok; can you post the content of your htaccess here?